# Нужна ли запятая перед «как» в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, как

> Семья как реабилитирующая структура

В буклете.
Есть ощущение, что не нужна, но не пойму, на какое правило ссылаться.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

**Семья как реабилитирующая структура** (= семья в качестве реабилитирующей структуры).

Запятая перед **как** не нужна — оборот не выделяется запятыми, если союз **как** имеет значение «в качестве».

*Аристотель вошёл в историю **как** ученик Платона и учитель Александра Македонского.*
Вошёл в качестве кого? Ученика Платона и учителя Македонского.

[Сравнительные обороты и обороты с КАК](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/725-29_sravnitelnye_oboroty_i_oboroty_s_kak.html)

Семья как реабилитирующий фактор для ребенка, пережившего жестокое обращение.
Семья как ячейка общества, как социальная группа — это предмет изучения одного из направлений в социологической науке — социологии...